# Add phpmyadmin in magento 2

Tags: magento, phpmyadmin, magento2

I want to add phpmyadmin to my online shop (that is in magento 2).
I downloaded phpmyadmin and paste in public_html.
But, when I try to access https://my-domain.com/phpmyadmin does not work.
Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? Do you see a blank page? An error message? Do you see the phpMyAdmin login page but your login information doesn't work? Is there anything in the webserver error log? What about the webserver access log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to ask to your server provider to install phpmyadmin in server.

You can refer below link to install phpmyadmin manually with your server SSH.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-16-04